# Can't Debug in Eclipse an Android App Blank Threads

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Any idea on how to fix Eclipse to show variables when breakpoint is reached, even the Debug pane shows the thread suspended and the code lines are blank under it

[image: (see picture 1)].

Seems this happens in versions 4.3 and 4.4 now.  Also you can't step through or into code (F5, F6,F7) you have to hit run (F8) to continue.  This is preventing me from debugging anything in android.  Seems to happen on inner calls like onClicks and such.

Comment: It happens in one specific device? On every device? Have you tried ie. on GenyMotion emulator? What is your ADT version? I can debug 4.3, 4.4, 4.4.4 apps flawlessly across a variety of devices

Comment: Not buying an emulator when I have a few devices, happens on all of them.  I have the latest versions and this started a few version back on ADT and tools and 4.3 Eclipse.  Seems to happen with onClick or ItemOnclick or other anon inner classes.

Comment: Seems related to this too since stepping into or over are greyed out,  http://stackoverflow.com/q/23546196/346309  ...Even adding Debug.waitForDebugger() doesn't work

Comment: I've given up on this in Eclipse and moved to Android Studio.  At least I can debug in Studio but even that is flaky.

Answer (score -1):

This response may seem silly but, I had the same issue with eclipse, and I fixed it with this method : click on the scrollbar (on the variable pane or thread pane) and move it up and down very fast, it should make appear the data (it worked for me)

[image: scrollbar]

Comment: Nope its not the variable pane its the Thread pane which also then disables stepping into code.  Please remove this answer as this does not solve my issue.

Comment: My trick could also work for the thread pane, have you give it a try ?

Comment: As I suspected it does not work...as i have said before the step into and step over are also greyed out.  My suspicion is that android is no longer working on this plugin and don't care for ADT since they are telling everyone to use the Android Studio bloat instead.

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen the code lines in the explorer its always in the actual code.  Try to reset the perspective sometimes it gets messed up.

In the debug perspective  menu window/ reset perspective...

menu

window / show view / variables

window / show view / expressions

or hover mouse on the variable.

Sometimes my f5 f6 f7 get broke and I have to restart eclipse.

You should be migrating to android studio anyways the debugging is totally different for example one click to set a breakpoint.  Myself I had a huge learning curve unlearning the double click set a breakpoint.